# How to format USB mass storage programmatically in android

Tags: android, format, usb-mass-storage

Is there any way to format a USB mass storage device programmatically in Android? I need to detect USB mass storage devices and give an option to format it. Any examples will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no support for any of this in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

May be help this:
I formatted external sd card from console with root permissions + busybox. I did it on china mobile:
 busybox mkfs.vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0